# Doesn't a pointer to an array point to 1st element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The following code shows a pointer pointing to first element of array.
The **ptr** shows the address it is pointing to whereas  ***ptr** is printing the value at the address, *which is expected.*

```
int arr[]={1,2};
int *ptr=arr; //same as int *ptr=&arr[0]
cout<<"\n\n";
cout<<"Value at "<<ptr<<"is "<<*ptr<<endl;
```

**Output:**

```
Value at 003CFB48is 1
```

In the following code the pointer is pointing to an array of 2 elements(instead of particularly pointing to an element of an array). But in this case dereferencing the pointer prints the address. 
**ptr2** prints the address then why doesnt ***ptr2** print the value at the address?

```
int arr2[]={3,4};
int (*ptr2)[2]=&arr2;
cout<<"Value at "<<ptr2<<"is "<<*ptr2<<endl; //Isnt *ptr2 supposed to print value at ptr?
cout<<"1st element is "<<**ptr2<<" and second is "<<*(*ptr2+1);
```

**Output:**

```
Value at 003CFB2Cis 003CFB2C
1st element is 3 and second is 4
```

Edit:
It would have been fine if **ptr** prints an address, `*ptr` prints some value,`**ptr` prints the first element(except i would have posted a different question then :) )
I understand that **ptr2** here points to an array and not the first element so i might be required to use `**ptr2` to print the first element.
The question here really is that if **ptr2** is pointing to *some* address then syntatically why would not ***ptr2** print the value at *that* address.

Comment: There are (more or less subtle) differences between a pointer to the first element and the array. However what you're doing in the second example is taking the "address" of `arr2` which means a pointer to the array (which acts somewhat like a pointer to a pointer). So why shouldn't you expect that behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

Although the numeric value of the two pointers is the same, the difference in their type makes dereference return different things:

- Dereferencing a pointer to `int` returns an `int`, while
- Dereferencing a pointer to an `int` array of two elements returns an `int` array of two elements.

When you pass operator `<<` the dereferenced pointer to an array, it gets a pointer to the first element of that array. Numerically, it's the same pointer, but it is still a pointer. That is why `003CFB2C` gets printed.

Note that the expression `*(*ptr2+1)` does not add much value, because `*` has higher precedence than `+`. `1` sis added to a *dereferenced* `ptr2`, which behaves like a pointer to `int`.

Trying to print `*(*(ptr2+1))`, however, would be undefined behavior, because it would point past the end of `arr2`. Here is a way to demonstrate what happens when you add `1` to a pointer to an array:

```
int arr2[2][2]={{3,4},{5,6}};
int (*ptr2)[2]=&arr2[0];
cout<<"Value at "<<ptr2<<"is "<<*ptr2<<endl; //Isnt *ptr2 supposed to print value at ptr?
cout<<"1st element is "<<**ptr2<<" and second is "<<*(*(ptr2+1));
```

Now `1st element is 3 and second is 5` gets printed ([demo](http://ideone.com/zWJZ4a)), because `ptr2+1` points to the next array of two `int`s, i.e. `{5, 6}`, its first derefnerence produces the array itself, and its second dereference produces the value at the initial location.

Comment: @dashblinkenlight :  _the expression *(*ptr2+1) does not add much value, because * has higher precedence than +. That's why 4 that gets printed is simply 3+1, not the 4 from the location that follows_  seems not to be true. you can try the same example from the question and the second element as 7(or anything other than 4).  Even though * has higher precedence than +, *ptr2 at this moment still points to the memory location and hence adding 1 points to the next memory cell i.e. 7.

Comment: @anurag86 You are right. I edited this part to explain what's going on.

Comment: Would the behavior be undefined? Or ptr+x would be in the multiples of the size of array. Example : If the pointer to array is of size 3, then ptr+3 would jump 6 locations. Wouldn't it always be the case and hence not UB?

Comment: @anurag86 The `+` operation would cause no UB, but the `*` on the result would. `ptr2+x` moves in increments of `sizeof`, but in this case that's the `sizeof(int[2])`. If `ptr2` points to `arr` in your example, `ptr2+1` would be past the end of `arr`, so dereferencing it would be UB. That is why I added another dimension to the array, so that adding `1` to my `ptr2` would land in a valid location.

Answer (score 2):

`int (*ptr2)[2]=&arr2;` This is a pointer to an array.

`ptr2` is a pointer to an array. When you print it, you get the address pointed at (the address of the array).

`*ptr2` is the array itself. Whenever an array is used in an expression, it decays into a pointer to the first element. When you print the pointer to the first element, you get the address of the first element. Which is also the address of the array.

`**ptr2` First you dereference the array pointer and get an array. The array decays into a pointer to the first element. Then you take the contents of the pointer to the first element and therefore the first element is printed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`*ptr2` is printing the address of `arr` ,`ptr2` is a pointer to an array.

Comment: Yes :( Should i delete my answer?

Comment: That's up to you, although the down votes seem to be disappearing now that you have fixed the post.